# Where can I find the "Search" section in the new Office365 SharePoint Admin Center?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365, sharepoint-admin-center

Where can I find the "Search" section in the new SharePoint Admin Center?

And if this has not been integrated into the new Admin Centre yet, does anyone have any idea whether this will be added in at a future date?

This is what I am referring to in the classic Admin Center:

[image: Office365 Sharepoint Admin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Search is not available in the new SharePoint Online Admin Center now.

From the post below, we can know that this feature will be added in the future:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Ignite-Content-2017/Manage-SharePoint-using-the-new-Sharepoint-Admin-Center/td-p/99099